# getting a return value from a function into another sub routine

Tags: vb.net

I have the below code which returns the premium amount but i am not sure how to get this to display in another function. The sub routine i want to get the value into just displays text about the options selected then i need to display the value calculated based on those results.

```
Function ProcessClaims(ClaimsList As claimsList, PremiumIn As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim adjustedPremium, originalPremium As Decimal
    Dim declined As Decimal
    originalPremium = ClaimsList.claimValue * 100 \ 5
    If ClaimsList.claimValue <= 5000 And ClaimsList.isPersonalInjury = False Then
        adjustedPremium = originalPremium
    ElseIf ClaimsList.claimValue > 5000 And ClaimsList.claimValue <= 10000 And ClaimsList.isPersonalInjury = False Then
        adjustedPremium = originalPremium * 100 / 10
    ElseIf ClaimsList.claimValue > 10000 Or ClaimsList.isPersonalInjury = False Then
        adjustedPremium = -1.0
        declined = -1.0
    End If
    If adjustedPremium = -1.0 Then
        PremiumIn = declined
    Else
        PremiumIn = adjustedPremium
    End If
    Return PremiumIn
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You're asking us how to call a method and use the return value.  That's programming 101.  You need to read a beginners tutorial to learn the basics and ask here about the hard stuff, that you can't work out even after doing appropriate research.

Comment: Can you post the other method?

Comment: This looks like VB.NET code? VBA is a little different. Instead of using the `Return` keyword you need to send the information back like this in the last line before `End Function`: `ProcessClaims = PremiumIn` - in other words, assign the value to be passed back to the function's name. (Note that if you're passing back an object, such as an Excel.Range, you would need to use `Set`, but that's not the case, here.)

Comment: How does this relate to both VBA and VB.NET? Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to call this VB.NET method from VBA code? If not, please remove the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward ..

Your sub/function that displays the result should be defined as something like

```
Private Sub DisplayStuff(premiumInResult as decimal)
    'display the value premiumInResult in here
End Sub
```

You can then either do this which is clearer

```
Dim result As Decimal = ProcessClaims(yourClaimsList , yourPremiumIn)
DisplayStuff(result)
```

or

```
Displaystuff(ProcessClaims(yourClaimsList , yourPremiumIn))
```

which is shorter but less clear, and makes debugging more difficult